# Henon Map Parameter

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals, chaos-theory

In case of Hennon map two parameters $a$ and $b$ to be set.The Hénon map takes a point $(x_n, y_n)$ in the plane and maps it to a new point $x_{n+1} = 1-a x_n^2 + y_n$, $y_{n+1} = b x_n$. The map depends on two parameters, a and b, which for the classical Hénon map have values of a = 1.4 and b = 0.3. For the classical values the Hénon map is chaotic.

What are other value of $a$ and $b$ for which we would also get chaotic nature? Can anyone suggest interval for $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1):

You can check a bifurcation diagram or a graph of maximum Lyapunov exponents to find other values which lead to chaos. Below is the bifurcation diagram for b=0.3 and varying values of a. Chaotic intervals are obvious.

[image]

Comment: Is the Interval [1.3, 1.4] for a? What about for b?

Comment: No. As you can see around 1.3 there is a periodic window and as I said b=0.3 for this bifurcation diagram. You should constitute your own bifurcation diagram similarly for varying values of b.